# Expedia hotel API

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on Expedia hotel API.All the function are working except booking.All the other request using GET method for requesting.But in booking we have to use the POST method with different URL.So i changed the URL for request but still getting the error.
My codes are

```
 HotelServicesImplService client = new HotelServicesImplService();
    HotelRoomReservationRequest bookreq = new HotelRoomReservationRequest();
    HotelRoomReservationResponse bookres = new HotelRoomReservationResponse();
    addressInfo bookad = new addressInfo();
    reservationInfo bookinfo = new reservationInfo();
    client.Url = "https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3";

    //bookreq.minorRevSpecified = true;
    //bookreq.minorRev = 25;
    bookreq.hotelId = 106347;
    bookreq.apiKey = "api";
    bookreq.cid = "cid";
    bookreq.arrivalDate = "12/11/2013";
    bookreq.departureDate = "12/13/2013";
    bookreq.supplierType = SupplierType.E;
    bookreq.rateKey = "af00b688-acf4-409e-8bdc-fcfc3d1cb80c";
    bookreq.roomTypeCode = "198058";
    bookreq.rateCode = "484072";
    bookreq.RoomGroup = new[] { new Room
    {
        numberOfAdults=Convert.ToInt32(2),
        numberOfChildren=Convert.ToInt32(0),
        childAges=new int[] {} ,
        firstName="Test Booking",
        lastName="Test Booking",
        bedTypeId="23",
        smokingPreference=SmokingPreference.NS,
    }};
    float i = float.Parse("231.18");
    bookreq.currencyCode = "USD";
    bookreq.chargeableRate = i;
    bookinfo.email = "ranaabhi007@yahoo.com";
    bookinfo.firstName = "TestBooking";
    bookinfo.lastName = "TestBooking";
    bookinfo.homePhone = "2145370159";
    bookinfo.workPhone = "2145370159";
    bookinfo.creditCardType = "CA";
    bookinfo.creditCardNumber = "5401999999999999";
    bookinfo.creditCardIdentifier = "TestBooking";
    bookinfo.creditCardExpirationMonth = "12";
    bookinfo.creditCardExpirationYear = "2015";
    bookad.city = "Seattle";
    bookad.stateProvinceCode = "WA";
    bookad.countryCode = "US";
    bookad.postalCode = "98004";
    bookreq.ReservationInfo = bookinfo;
    bookad.address1 = "travelnow";
    //bookad.city = txtCity.Text;
    //bookad.stateProvinceCode = txtState.Text;
    //bookad.countryCode = txtCountry.Text;
    //bookad.postalCode = txtPostal.Text;
    bookreq.AddressInfo = bookad;
    bookres = client.getReservation(bookreq);
   // HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(client);
    Response.Write(bookres.confirmationNumbers);
    Response.Write(bookres.departureDate);
    Response.Write(bookres.drivingDirections);
    Response.Write(bookres.CouponInformationResponse);
```

but i am still getting the error

```
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to reserve a room using the API??

Comment: Is this the same question as your [Request Method For web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902375/request-method-for-web-api)? For future reference, you can edit questions.

Comment: Clearly your url is incorrect. Hence "Not found".

Comment: "The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found." that's what your answer is. https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3 does not exist i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your URL is correct?  According to the [documentation](http://developer.ean.com/docs/book-reservation/), it should be

```
https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res
```

Comment: URL is correct.I tried this URL also but getting the same ERROR.

Comment: Be sure to use POST.  GET returns 405 (Method not allowed) with the above URL.  This is different than 404 (Not found).

Comment: with above URL getting ERROR
Client found response content type of 'application/json', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:

Comment: Yes, it looks like the API has two different response formats, either JSON or XML.  Your error message is saying that the client is expecting XML, so you need to indicate to the server that is the response format you want it to send back.